# rename command with perl expression

Tags: rename

I can use the following command successfully, and I'm quite confident with this command to make other combinations:

```
rename 's/\.htm/\.html/' *.htm
```

However I want to know more about it, especially about `s` in it. They say it is a Perl expression. I haven't learned Perl programming language, so I have no idea why there is such a `'s/\.htm/\.html/'` argument. Would you tell me what it is?? Thanks for reading.

Comment: fyi: I use [code irregularly in] perl, but don't think of it as a perl expression. if you put a ':' in front of the s it would be a vi [line] command I learned in the 80s before perl was released.  the construct exists in many *nix tools

Comment: as for learning about it, maybe look up 'regular expressions' (if interested). The construct is also found in sed (stream editing), and (heaps more)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/rename.ul.1.html) renames the *filenames* supplied according to the rule specified as the first argument of the command. The the *filenames* are supplied by the arguments that follow the first one.

The first argument in the example command (`rename 's/\.htm/\.html/' *.htm`) has fur parts, where in this case `/` is a delimiter of these parts:

```
s/regexp/replacement/[flags]
```

1. The `s` command means substitute: `s/<old>/<new>/`. Match the regular-expression against the content of the pattern space. If found, replace matched string with replacement.
2. Regular expression that matches to the strings that should be substituted. In the current case this is just the string `.htm`.

   In most regular expressions the dot `.` matches to every character. In this case we want to use the dot literally, so we need to escape its special meaning by using the back slash `\` (quoting a single character).
3. Replacement of the sting/regexp matched to 2.
4. Flag that is not presented in the current example. It could be for example the flag `g` - apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first. Let's assume we have a file named `my.htm-file.htm`:

   - The original command `rename 's/\.htm/\.html/' *.htm` will rename the file in this way: `my.html-file.htm`. **Look at the bottom of the answer how to avoid this problem.**
   - By adding the `g` flag - `rename 's/\.htm/\.html/g' *.htm` - the new filename will be: `my.html-file.html`.

According to the filenames: `*` can represent any number of characters (including zero, in other words, zero or more characters). The shell will [expand that glob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion), and it passes the matching filenames as separate arguments to `rename` So `*.htm` - will match to all filenames in the current path that end with the string `.htm`. For example if you have `1.htm`, `2.htm`, `3.htm`, `4.htm`, and `5.htm` then `rename 's/\.htm/\.html/' *.htm` passes exactly the same arguments to rename as running:

```
rename 's/\.htm/\.html/' 1.htm 2.htm 3.htm 4.htm 5.htm
```

---

The whole command  (`rename 's/\.htm/\.html/' *.htm`) could be read in this way:

```
rename `<substitute>/<the string ".htm">/<with the string ".html">/` <do it for all files in the current path that end with ".htm">
```

---

Let's go back to the example when we have a file named `my.htm-file.htm`. Probably we want to change the last part of the filename so called extension after the last dot. For this purpose we should modify the `rename` command in this way:

```
rename 's/\.htm$/\.html/' *.htm
```

Where the `$` sign matches to the end of the line and literally means "read backward".

> `^` - Matches the null string at beginning of the pattern space, i.e.
>   what appears after the circumflex must appear at the beginning of the
>   pattern space. ([*read more*](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax))
>
> `^` acts as a special character only at the beginning of the regular
>   expression or subexpression (that is, after `\(` or `\|`). Portable
>   scripts should avoid `^` at the beginning of a subexpression, though, as
>   POSIX allows implementations that treat `^` as an ordinary character in
>   that context.
>
> `$` - It is the same as `^`, but refers to end of pattern space. `$` also
>   acts as a special character only at the end of the regular expression
>   or subexpression (that is, before `\)` or `\|`), and its use at the end of
>   a subexpression is not portable.

---

References:

- [Bash Guide for Beginners: Shell expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html)
- [GNU/Linux Command-Line Tools Summary: Wildcards](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)
- [perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [GNU: sed, a stream editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)
- [Online regular expression testers](https://www.google.bg/search?q=online%20regular%20expression&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBG704BG704&oq=online%20regular&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5095j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: s for substitute. Alright. Thanks for your answer. Many people are gonna benefit from your answer. Have a nice day:)

Comment: *"the second argument, that is file name match expression"* No, `rename` never sees `*.htm`. Before it runs `rename`, the shell [expands that glob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion), and it passes the matching filenames as *separate* arguments to `rename`. If you have `1.htm`, `2.htm`, `3.htm`, `4.htm`, and `5.htm` then `rename 's/\.htm/\.html/' *.htm` passes *exactly* the same arguments to `rename` as running `rename 's/\.htm/\.html/' 1.htm 2.htm 3.htm 4.htm 5.htm`. Are you willing to edit--or accept an edit--to correct that? This answer is otherwise good.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Thank you for this note! I've made an edit.