# Change multiple filenames by replacing commas and whitespaces with underscores

Tags: files

My files are of the format

```
Country, City S1.txt
```

e.g.

```
USA, Los Angeles S1.txt
USA, San Francisco S3.txt
UK, Glouchester S4.txt
Argentina, Buenos Aires S7.txt
```

I wish to change them to

```
Country_City_S1.txt
```

e.g.

```
USA_Los_Angeles_S1.txt
USA_San_Franciso_S3.txt
UK_Glouchester_S4.txt
Argentina_Buenos_Aires_S7.txt
```

Can someone help me please, preferably using the `mv` command? Thanks.

Comment: There is 1 thing missing from the question: How do you want duplicates handeled?

Comment: @Rinzwind Since there are no duplicates now, in what circumstances might one expect duplicates in the process of renaming?

Comment: 1. already existing `Country_City_S1.txt` or 2 files with names `Country, City S1.txt` + `Country City S1.txt`.  Mind there is another issue: he said commas AND spaces. So `Country, City S1.txt` should technically be replaced to `Country__City_S1.txt`  (3x _) and either the title is wrong or the body ;-) Seems nitpicking but ... `mv` is not so forgiving when it comes to duplicates so better safe than sorry :D

Comment: Agree with sentiment of Rinzwind here. It's always important to at least acknowledge the possibility of duplicate/filename clash when renaming, and confirm that it is not an issue in our data before moving on, since as Rinzwind said, `mv` is not very forgiving on that.

Answer (score 8):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.txt; do # Work on files with ".txt" extension in the current working directory assigning their names one at a time(for each loop run) to the variable "$f"
    IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$f" # Split filename into parts/elements by "," and " " and read the elements into an array
    f1=$(IFS="_$IFS"; printf "${array[*]}"; IFS="${IFS:1}") # Set the new filename in the variable "$f1" by printing array elements and adding "_" inbetween.
    echo mv -n -- "$f" "$f1" # Renaming dry-run(simulation) ... Remove "echo" when satisfied with output to do the actual renaming.
done
```

or

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob # Turn on "extglob"

for f in *.txt; do # Work on files with ".txt" extention in the current working directory assigning their namese one at a time(for each loop run) to the fariable "$f"
    echo mv -n -- "$f" "${f//+([, ])/_}" # Renaming dry-run(simulation) ... Remove "echo" when satisfied with output to do the actual renaming.
done
```

Answer (score 8):

It's simple with Perl's [`rename`](https://metacpan.org/dist/File-Rename/view/rename.PL) (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45641840/4970442) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/982092/349837); [don't get confuse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22578623/4970442) with the other rename):

```sh
rename 's/,? /_/g' *.txt     # Or rename 's/(, | )/_/g' *.txt
```

Could be used with `-vn`: `--verbose` (print names of files successfully renamed) and `--nono` (print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that adding `-vn` would allow one to view the renames without doing them.

Answer (score 3):

If you are comfortable at all in vim and are not opposed to using something besides `mv`, you might consider [vimv](https://www.dmulholl.com/dev/vimv.html). I like it for batch renaming because it lets me see what I'm doing before I do it. (And because I like vim.)

**EDIT 2022-07-08:** Upon re-reading the docs, it appears you don't have to use vim. It's possible to tell vimv to use a different editor.

**EDIT 2022-07-09:** It was pointed out to me that my answer doesn't provide enough detail to be considered an answer to the question.

The vimv approach to renaming (or deleting) files is to open the file listing in your preferred text editor. There, you edit each filename to whatever you wish it to be, however you do that in your editor. (To delete the file, replace it with a blank line.) Upon exiting the editor, the files are moved (or removed) according to your edits.

Comment: the answer does not say how to accomplish the task

Comment: @qwr That's because vimv doesn't provide multiple approaches to the task. I'll admit, though, that I could have described the process. I'll make the edit.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

`for i in * ; do echo mv "$i" $(echo $i | tr -s ' ,' '_') ; done`

- For everyfile
- move the file to the filename with spaces and commas replaced by a single underscore.

Comment: As in other answers you may want --no-clobber/-n (see `man mv`) so you don't overwrite files by accident.

Answer (score 1):

For any POSIX shell (as well as Bash), the below will work, run from the directory containing the files, and skip any conversions creating a duplicate output.

```
for f in *.txt; do mv -n "$f" `echo "$f" |sed  -e "s/[, ]\+/_/g"`; done
```

The above will even work in dash/ash, a more limited shell than bash.

A more modern notation as noted (with the closure syntax fixed is:

```
for f in *.txt; do mv -n "$f" $(echo "${f//+([, ])/_}"); done
```

Comment: Nice. You could use the more [modern notation](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006); and [`${file//[, ]\+/_}`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2001)

Comment: @Pablo Bianchi  Always good to eliminate another executable, but the bash closure syntax is different. Updated the answer.

Comment: Did you encounter cases where `mv -n "$f" "${f//+([, ])/_}";` break (in bash)?

Comment: $ foo='foo,bar, bif,  bang.txt'  
$ echo ${foo//[, ]\+/_}   
foo,bar, bif, bang.txt
Might need some environment var to make it work, but the default is fail for the syntax in your first comment (second comment syntax is what works by default).

Comment: I still don't understand the need of `echo`, at least with `extglob` on. I notice Raffa already added this option

Comment: @Pablo Bianchi Ha, left in the extra echo from the testing, removed it in answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something nearer to `mv`, you may try `mmv` which operates on a globbing pattern. For example,

```
mmv "*",\ "*" "#1"_"#2"
```

will convert all `,\`  to `_`. So applying `mmv` two more times will get what you want with your example. It is available in the repository and its manual page is very informative, too.

Of course, regex may be a better way to go if your filenames do not fall into a nice globbable pattern.